# Skip usage of <p> and go with <br> instead

Tags: html, line-breaks

I am building a CMS and I wonder if I can skip the usage of paragraphs and only go with  linebreaks in the text content.

1. Is it a good or bad idea?
2. Will Google treat the content different in any way not using any paragraphs?
3. What about allowing "double linebreaks" or even more linebreaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad idea, for several reasons:

1. browsers will no longer be able to properly flow text in boxes, which is likely to result in a lot of linebreaks in places you are not expecting. This is likely to get worse if users change the fontsize in their browser.
2. Using one or more breaks to get the right amount of vertical spacing in a page is not a useful way to get consistent styling in your site. It is much simpler to use a bit of CSS to get the right spacing between paragraphs and other elements.

Comment: Thanks Wichert, 1) linebreaks will be at the same place br-end tag would be, so I don't see your point (am I thinking wrong)? 2) The end user of the CMS almoast demands this feature since CSS is to har for them :S

Comment: I can guarantee you what will happen is that someone is entering content like this: "This is a bit of sample text that should be formatted<br/>just as I am entering it here." and it will be rendered like this: "This is a bit of sample text that should be<newline>formatted<newline>just as I am entering it here.", because the browser will be wraping the text to fit the available with anyway. A CMS should hide all CSS requirements for the user and do things right automatically, or you will end up with a system that will never work quite they way you (or your user) wants.

Comment: I was planning to use br-tag INSTEAD of the "end-p-tag", nothing else. But I think I go with what every one else is doing to be shore.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the article below. It covers `<p>`, `<hr>`, `<br>`, and `<pre>` tags:

http://www.pitstopmedia.com/sem/br-hr-p-pre-tag-seo

Comment: The article says: "search engines are looking for this tag" (the p-tag). "single<br>word" will be read and cached "singleword" (with out the space). I don't know if any of that is true :S

Answer (score 0):

Can you implement both? Ie when the user press enter, they get a paragraph. When they press shift and enter they they get a line break. My work uses a cms that only uses br, I find it better to allow the use of both as p tags allow you to add styles to the paragraph etc.

As for google, I'm not 100% sure of their algorithms, but they may use

tags to paraphrase your page - I know they use  tags for many things, but it may be worth looking into.

You can use the br for fine control of the number of lines you want to add. Two br is about equal to the spacing after one set of p, but then with the p you can control the spacing with CSS.